# dc.js - avoid data points animation when adding data to scatter plot

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to implement a live data visualization (i.e. with new data arriving periodically) using dc.js. The problem I'm having is the following - when new data is added to the plot, already existing points often start to "dance around", even though they were not changed. Can this be avoided?

The [following fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ttmmff/414qwd8z/2/) illustrates this.

My guess is that crossfilter sorts data internally, which results in points moving on the chart for data items that changed their position (index) in the internal storage. Data is added in the following way:

```
var data = [];
var ndx = crossfilter(data)
setInterval(function() {
            var value = ndx.size() + 1;
            if (value > 50) {
                return;
            }
            var newElement = {
                x: myRandom(),
                y: myRandom()
            };

            ndx.add([newElement]);
            dc.redrawAll();
        }, 1000);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd characterize the problem a little more like: Crossfilter groups and dimensions both return ordered data, but d3.js (what dc.js is built on) defaults to assuming that data points are identified by their index in the data array. I think that the dc.js scatter plot could be updated to use the group key as the index instead? Not sure. It would have to happen here, I believe: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/scatter-plot.js#L79

Comment: thanks for answer! I've briefly looked into the source, by my js skills are not enough here. I can see there is a disableTransitions switch, but it blocks all animations, which makes the plots slightly rough. For my current project, disabling data points movements, and keeping all other animations would be enough. Any idea how to patch dc to have this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but theoretically from a d3.js perspective, `.data(_chart.data());` would become `.data(_chart.data(), function(d) { return d.something_unique_per_data_point });`. I think you'd have access to the group key inside that function, so you could use that. I would recommend opening on issue in the dc.js repository and referencing this discussion.

Comment: `.transitionDuration(0)` on the scatter plot only?

Comment: I agree with @Ethan, the data should really be bound using a key function, at least optionally. There's some discussion of it [in this ticket](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/621), so I don't think there's any need to open a new ticket. (A pull request would be awesome, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stand by my comments above. dc.js should be fixed by binding the data using a key function, and probably the best way to deal with the problem is just to disable transitions on the scatterplot using `.transitionDuration(0)`

However, I was curious if it was possible to work around the current problems by keeping the group in a set order using a fake group. And it is indeed, at least for this example where there is no aggregation and we just want to display the original data points.

First, we add a third field, `index`, to the data. This has to order the data in the same order in which it comes in. As noted in the discussion above, the scatter plot is currently binding data by its index, so we need to keep the points in a set order; nothing should be inserted.

```
      var newElement = {
        index: value,
        x: myRandom(),
        y: myRandom()
      };
```

Next, we have to preserve this index through the binning and aggregation. We could keep it either in the key or in the value, but keeping it in the key seems more fitting:

```
      xyiDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
        return [+d.x, +d.y, d.index];
      }),
      xyiGroup = xyiDimension.group();
```

The original reduction didn't make sense to me, so I dropped it. We'll just use the default behavior, which counts the number of rows which fall into each bin. The counts should be 1 if included, or 0 if filtered out. Including the index in the key also ensures uniqueness, which the original keys were not guaranteed to have.

Now we can create a fake group that keeps everything sorted by index:

```
    var xyiGroupSorted = {
      all: function() {
        var ret = xyiGroup.all().slice().sort((a,b) => a.key[2] - b.key[2]);
        return ret;
      }
    }
```

This will fetch the original data whenever it's requested by the chart, create a copy of the array (because the original is owned by crossfilter), and sort it to return it to the correct order.

And voila, we have a scatter plot that behaves the way it should, even though the data has gone through crossfilter.

Fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/mj81m42v/13/

[After all this, maybe we shouldn't have given the data to crossfilter in the first place! We could have just created a fake group which exposes the original data. But maybe there's some use to this technique. At least it proves that there's almost always a way to work around any problems in dc.js & crossfilter.]